# How to use Spring Boot with Spring Data in a module without an actual Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have to write a small project, which is not runnable by itself, but it is used by some other ("main") project as dependency to do some database operations and some simple business logic. So there will be no actual main class in my project, only some API, which will be used by the main project. Now I was wondering, if it is possible, to use Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA in my small project for Database operations. So there will be no `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. (And the main project is also not a Spring Boot application)

So I actually modified my `pom.xml` by adding this:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

(...)

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

Also I added an `application.properties` file in `resources` folder:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
```

And finally, I added a simple config file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories("package-of-the-JPA-repositories")
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan("package-of-the-entities")
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class SpringConfig {
    
}
```

Well, this configuration done, I tried to run the main project, but it sais, it cannot find the `entityManagerFactory` bean. As I understood, Spring Boot should generate this bean from the specified properties. So my question would be: 1) Is the thing I am tring to do generally possible? Means, is it possible to use Spring Boot without having an `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class? Or should I rather get rid of Spring Boot and use only Spring Data and Hibernate? And if it is possible, what am I possibly doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: You're trying to write a small project that isn't runnable by itself, but then you try to run it by itself? It's doable, and you can get it to compile. To run it you would need at least some kind of test harness that has the required parts.

Comment: Maybe I didn't write it clear enough: I did not run my small project (which I want to use Spring Boot), but i ran the "main" project, which uses it as a maven dependency and which is not a Spring Boot application.

Comment: You know that Spring Boot depends on a lot of autoconfiguration. If you want to get rid of that and go to regular Spring, you'll have to configure everything yourself. Your main project is still a Spring project, right?

Comment: Yes, the main project is still a Spring project. Yes, I know, that Spring Boot does a lot of configuration under the hood - which was actually the reason, why I was trying to use it. But as I got the described error, I began to wonder, if it is doable at all in my case (without an actual Spring Boot application)

Comment: Why? If I understood you correctly it shouldn't be the small project isn't doing any configuration by itself anyway. It should depend on the configuration done by the main application. What good would Spring Boot bring you with it's autoconfig when you don't need to configure anything?

Comment: It's really confusing that your main app isn't a Spring Boot app, where it would be the most useful. Yet you're trying to shoehorn Spring Boot into the separate module that can't configure itself as it's not standalone anyway.

Comment: Well, I know it is a bit confusing. I have no possibility to switch the main project to Spring Boot. In the small project, I was trying to use Spring Boot to minimize the effort of database configuration (just adding the properties file and the config class above). So you say, this won't work, as Spring Boot will not be able to autoconfigure this project?

Comment: It seems you're talking constantly about Spring Boot, when you should be talking about Spring. Your main application is a Spring app, not a Spring Boot application. Your module will be a Spring module, and it will have nothing to do with Spring Boot.